# Protecting microcontroller from surges

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply

I'm trying to come up with a way to effectively protect a microcontroller from voltage surges from the line. The microcontroller is powered via a 230 V to 12 V transformer and a linear voltage regulator.

Right now I've added a PTC fuse and a MOV that should clamp the surge at 35-43 V, but the absolute maximum rating for the linear voltage regulator is 38 V.

I was thinking about putting a zener diode to clamp the spike after the bridge rectifier and before the linear voltage regulator. Would this be a good approach?

What I don't really understand is how should I calculate the series resistor for the zener diode in this application?

[image]

Comment: What is the source of the spike and what are you actually trying to protect?

Comment: put a much bigger filter cap on to absorb the voltage.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a very good transformer symbol, but, I guess it's a transformer?  So I'm going with that.  It seems to have a datasheet:

https://www.tme.com/Document/cb1d7fdbe3570188ff28030ca3a4f1cf/Catalogue%20Myrra%202018%20compress%C3%A9.pdf (part number 44328, see page 9 (7))

The manfacturer says:

> Inherently short-circuits proof

> No-load voltage V  20,2

Rated for 12V at 125mA, but 20V open-circuit, this transformer has *considerable* internal resistance (and impedance, but mostly resistance as it happens).

"Impedance protected" or "short-circuit proof" type transformers are constructed with enough resistance in the windings, and adequate insulation type/rating, that they can be operated indefinitely* into a short circuit.  This is *not* the platonic ideal of a transformer.

*Within whatever scope the standards (EN60950, UL5085) prescribe, and whatever failure mechanism (if any) is acceptable (e.g. melting and smoldering but no direct-flame ignition, or self-extinguishing flame within some duration, etc.).

---

What is surge?  IEC 61000-4-5 surge is a typical standard describing representative surge waveforms and testing methods, that arise due to lightning induced transients on typical mains distribution networks.

For example, a test might be 2kV 8/20µs (meaning: 10-90% rise time / FWHM* pulse duration), with a "2Ω equivalent" surge generator having a specified circuit and waveform.  That is, a short-circuit peak current of 1kA is possible, and on the order of 20J energy delivered.

*Full Width Half Maximum, i.e. time between rising above, then below, 50% of maximum (peak) value.

Such levels are quite destructive to semiconductor devices, and many circuits in general, so some means of limiting them is desirable.

---

The high impedance of this transformer is relevant here.  If the transformer has an apparent (20.2V - 12V) / 0.125A = 65.6Ω output resistance, or (230V / 12V)<sup>2</sup> times or 24.1kΩ primary-referred, that acts in series with the surge generator's 2Ω output resistance, cutting its current down to a mere 62mA.  Or 1.2A at the secondary.

1.2A into 220µF for 20µs is a change of only ΔV = I Δt / C or 0.11V.  The normal operating ripple voltage is likely higher, and no surge is noticeable in circuit.

Note that the fuse (400mA PTC type) never opens, because the transformer's short-circuit current is only about 310mA.  Note also the MOV never does anything, because secondary voltage is clamped by the rectifier and capacitor, to about 28V open circuit, and about 16V at rated load.  (A primary fuse isn't strictly useful, or necessary even, for the same reason; but a 1A fuse at the mains inlet is still a wise precaution in case of wiring mistakes, or catastrophic failure of the transformer.)

Both voltages, by the way, are far too high for direct connection to a microcontroller; a regulator is required.  Which affords further surge immunity, in case perhaps C9's ESR is much higher than expected (it could be several ohms and nothing much would change in this analysis).

Answer (score 2):

No such protection is necessary with low-frequency mains transformers. They don't really pass much in the way of large transients.

Use a wideband LDO to ensure that differential AC components up to a couple hundred kHz are suppressed on the secondary side.

If there's a PE connection available, it is sometimes useful to have a suitable TVS (transient voltage suppressor) between the secondary side and PE, connected right at the secondary of the transformer, to shunt large common-mode transients, and also to protect the transformer against insulation breakdown from ESD transients induced on the secondary side. That would usually be a human (or an ESD gun :) touching and "zapping" the low-voltage connectors/controls, potentially damaging the mains transformer due to breaking down its insulation. The TVS would need similar rating to the peak rating of transformer primary-to-secondary insulation - to protect it from breaking over.

If this is a double-insulated design without a PE connection on the mains input, then there's really no need for any overvoltage protection on the input. The transformer's primary-to-secondary peak voltage (transient) insulation rating and primary-to-secondary capacitance are the main specifications to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

To protect a circuit, you need to refer to some norms. I don't see the exact fault you are trying to protect for. But, here are my toughts:

A zener diode in series with a resistor won't be that useful. For the diode to offer a good protection, you would need to ensure that the maximum voltage that you could see (depending on the norm you want to comply) would not blow your diode. So let's say that could place 38V zener diode that can take 100mA, you can find the resistor quite easily: R=V/I=(43-38)/0.1=50. Therefore, you need a 50 ohm resistor to protect your diode.

This might be suitable in some applications, but in most, I doubt it. You should probably design a bit more convoluted circuit using a mosfet or something similar. Sometimes the strategy might be to blow or trip a fuse. In other you might want to use a MOV or PTC. It really depends on what norm you need to comply to.

Answer (score 1):

If you're mostly worried about momentary blips on the mains, simply specifying a more appropriate regulator might be a better approach. The transformer itself will saturate and prevent really egregious spikes, in fact that's one of the **advantages** of using a transformer.

For example, a 5V 200mA regulator in SOT89 with 80V abs-max input is available for about dime in quantity. If you need more than a few tens of mA SOT89 may not be appropriate, but then you'll likely be using a switching supply.